Firefox Extention onMessage sendResponse
I'm having a pretty frustrating problem with these firefox extensions. Specifically, the problem is that I cannot obtain and then use the data following the sendResponse of onMessage.addListener. Here is a short description:

Here I manage the actions that must occur when starting "call_LLM_Api". Path background.js

browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(async (message, sender, sendResponse) => {
    console.log("Message recived form background script:", message);
    
    if (message.type === "call_LLM_Api") {
        try {
            console.log("Async logic...");

            sendResponse({ result: "testtt", angelolo: "ok done" });
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error in back script", error);
            sendResponse({ error: error.message });
        }

        return true;
    }
});


Here the function that makes the call, which in turn is called by other functions which are then handled by popup.js on the click of buttons. Path popup/training.js

async function ApiCall(data) {
    try {
        // cover browser.runtime.sendMessage in Promise
        const response = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            browser.runtime.sendMessage(
                {
                    type: "call_LLM_Api",
                    data: data,
                },
                (response) => {
                    if (browser.runtime.lastError) {
                        reject(new Error(browser.runtime.lastError.message));
                    } else if (!response) {
                        // Gestisce il caso in cui la risposta è undefined
                        reject(new Error("Response is undefined"));
                    } else if (response.error) {
                        reject(new Error(response.error));
                    } else {
                        resolve(response);
                    }
                }
            );
        });

        console.log("background response script:", response);
        return response.result; // Ritorna il risultato
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error in message send:", error);
        throw error; // Propaga l'errore
    }
}


Here is the manifest.json to define the working context a bit:

{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Policy Analyzer",
    "version": "1.0",
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },

    "description": "Analyze the Privacy policy you are accepting by accessing a web page.",
    "icons":{
      "16": "icons/icon-16.png",
      "48": "icons/icon-48.png",
      "128": "icons/icon-128.png"
    },

    "browser_action":
    {
      "default_icon":{
        "16": "icons/icon-16.png",
        "48": "icons/icon-48.png",
        "128": "icons/icon-128.png"
      },
      "default_title": "De Compile Privacy",
      "default_popup": "popup/popup.html"
    },
    "permissions": [
      "geolocation",
      "tabs",
      "activeTab",
      "http://*/*",
      "https://*/*",
      "storage",
      "webNavigation"
    ],
    
    "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js": ["content.js"]
      }
    ]
  }

So the problem seems to be that I can never get correct output from the calling function, it is always either undefined...
Error in message send: Error: Response is undefined

this problem seems quite serious and for this reason I ask you for support...
Thanks to anyone who wants to contribute!!

The problem is that your function is async, so it returns a Promise, not a literal true.
In Firefox you can simply return the value, no need for sendResponse and return true.
browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(async (message, sender) => {
  if (message.type === 'call_LLM_Api') {
    return {result: 'testtt', angelolo: 'ok done'};
  }
});

To enable the same code in Chrome you must polyfill it.
P.S. There's also no need to promisify browser API, it's already promisified.
